# Webpack with Vue JS 2.6 and VueCli 4.0

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to install Webpack with the `VueCli 4.0`.

With the older Deprecated Vue Cli running the command `vue init webpack my-project` would scaffold a webpack ready project with the options for babel, SASS, Linting, Router and vuex all in one project. However the packages seem very old and this is now deprecated.

The new version of the vue cli does not have the webpack.config file. I want to add a prerender to my project but don't know where to add it. Does it go into the vue.config.js file?

How can I create and add plugins such as a prerender with webpack and vue together using the latest version of vuejs which is currently 2.6.11 the VueCli 4.0?

Comment: You use `vue create <project>`

Comment: Vue create <project> creates a vue project, not one with webpack

Comment: Incorrect. It uses webpack. And if you want to [configure webpack](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack) you can do that too, especially using [webpack-chain](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack)

Comment: Ok that was my next question, so you just need to add and create the webpack.config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vue CLI has advanced quite alot. With much of the configuration now done behind the scenes. If you need to add plugins or further configuration, you just need to create the vue.config.js file if it has not already been created.

You can also use the Vue UI and search for plugins. If plugins are available vue just runs and installs what it needs. Pretty cool. Otherwise just add them in the vue.config.js file

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Vue with webpack you need to a webpack config file as below. The config file consists of a list of entry js files. I have added one, you can add many. These files will be emitted to a dist folder.

```
const path = require("path");

const {
  VueLoaderPlugin
} = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  watch: true,
  entry: {
    "main": "./src/main/main.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              sassOptions: {
                fiber: require('fibers'),
                //indentedSyntax: true // optional
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  }
};
```

Your entry js file will run the vue configurations and mount the app on to #app.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './Any_Vue_Component_1.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

And then you need to add the webpack emitted js file to your Html.

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <div id='app'></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

When you are executing webpack in your project directory you may get error messages from webpack about missing packages. Read the error messages and install the packages that is being asked. In normal case, you need sass, sass-loader, style-loader, vue-loader, vue-template-compiler, css-loader.

Comment: With the old CLI it installs all of this for you and wraps it in vue It creates a dev and prod versions of it...So I need to manually create a webpack.config file as you have listed here or is this something that the vue cli should generate?

Comment: Does the vue cli scafold all of this for you or do I need to manually add a webpack.conf file and somehow load it into my app?

Comment: Or do I need to create a webpack project with npm init first and then install vue into it or use the vue cli and then add webpack to it? Which way round?

Comment: To compile .vue files to .js files you need to use vue cli or webpack, there is no point in using both. Vue cli internally uses webpack. I use vue cli for single-page apps and webpack for multi-page applications. When using webpack, it emits file to dist folder, I will then include the same on to HTML file as shown in the answer. These HTML files are then served to the client-side by the server. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, It's absrtacted webpack internally, got it. I will use vue cli. However before it came with webpack.config file but not any more becuase of this reason. Where do you add your webpack plugins? do you manually have to create the webpack.config file and add plugins to it somewhere or use the vue.config.js as I want to add a prerenderer to my vue project

Comment: When you use vue cli you need to use vue config. It has an option to override the default configure of webpack. That looks complicated, I haven't done that circus yet. https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack. Please test and write a post in medium.com. I will glad to read and clap for it. :)