# Vuetify SassError: Expected newline

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I tried to add vuetify using webpack but getting SassError: Expected Newline

18:25:32 webpacker.1 | Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

18:25:32 webpacker.1 | SassError: Expected newline.

18:25:32 webpacker.1 |   ╷

18:25:32 webpacker.1 | 1 │ var api = require("!../../../../../style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");

Vuetify Plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

Installed Packages:

```
{
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "howler": "^2.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.18"
}
```

Loader Details:

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
  use: [
    'vue-style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
      options: {
        implementation: require('sass'),
        sassOptions: {
          fiber: require('fibers'),
          indentedSyntax: true // optional
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Please check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60333509/webpack-with-vue-js-2-6-and-vuecli-4-0/60334909#60334909

Answer (score 1):

Need to remove these loaders:

```
environment.loaders.delete('sass')
environment.loaders.delete('moduleSass')
environment.loaders.delete('moduleCss')
environment.loaders.delete('css')
```

And then need to add sass and scss loaders.

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2235

Comment: do u know how this can be achieved in a project not using webpacker? I dont have an environment.js file, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143692/vuetify-without-vue-cli-sass-scss-conflict